# after delete trigger and before delete trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

What can we handle in after delete triggers that we cannot handle in before delete trigger and vice-versa.

Also in case of insert trigger, what we can handle in before and not in after?

Exactly what is not possible with before delete trigger but possible with after trigger

Comment: Why do you asking for? What do you like to achieve (result)?

Comment: just an interview question.

Comment: Can you provide some more information and the code you have written so far? Your question is to broad. On the [ask]  page you find some helpful tips to improve your question.

Comment: In before you can change the data (to be inserted/updated), in after you can perform a select against the triggered table (in before you get mutating table exeption).

Comment: oracle made two different triggers before delete and after delete .............and for sure these two have some difference apart from one fire before insert and one fire after insert..????????? thats what i want to know

Comment: Are you on the interview now :)? Look here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/96263/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-before-update-and-after-update-trigger. There is difference in the purpose and timing between after and before triggers. E.g. after triggers can change the already inserted data, which used sequences.

Comment: Thats ok....the difference mentioned is in before insert and after insert.............................but mine question is difference in before delete and after delete

Comment: You can't change values of the inserted row in an after trigger (please check your keyboard, the `.` and `?` seem to be broken, as they insert too many characters when you press them)

Answer (score 1):

**1. Before triggers**

Before triggers can be used to update or validate record values before they are saved to the database.

Use Before Trigger:
In the case of validation check in the same object.
Insert or update the same object.

--

**2. After triggers**

After triggers can be used to access field values that are set by the database (such as a record's Id or lastUpdated field) and to affect changes in other records, such as logging into an audit table or firing asynchronous events with a queue.

Use After Trigger:
Insert/Update related object, not the same object.
Notification email.
We cannot use After trigger if we want to update a record because it causes read-only error. This is because, after inserting or updating, we cannot update a record.